# Editing Kernel command-line arguments inside Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, u-boot

U-boot passes kernel command-line parameters. In my requirement I want to edit these parameters in the kernel source tree and don't want to change U-boot code. I am using 2.6.35 kernel.

So please guide me which part of the kernel source I have to check for this.

Answer (score 5):

Follow this procedure:

- Enter the kernel config by typing `make menuconfig`
- Enter the menu *Processor type and features*
- Enable *Built-in kernel command line*
- Specify your command line by clicking on *Built-in kernel command string*
- Select *Built-in command line overrides boot loader arguments* if you want `bootargs` to be ignored

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems the CONFIG_CMDLINE defined in default config file is showing in make menuconfig(select Boot options ). I have to change at run-time based on GPIO value.

Comment: What do you mean "change at run-time" ? In the kernel config is a compile-time option. If you need run-time change, you'd better to understand how to change the bootargs parameter (e.g., by letting U-boot checking the GPIO through a proper run-time script)

Comment: While Kernel is coming up, I have to modify the kernel command-line. Example: say "console=ttyS0" is defined in CONFIG_CMDLINE, I have to change to "console=ttyS1" if gpio value is 1 else "console=ttyS0".

Comment: You can't change the boot command-line once the kernel has started. You need to find a different strategy. U-boot allows run scripts (i.e., programs). You can load in RAM a program in U-boot which checks the GPIO and then changes the bootargs parameter. It is easy and it does not need you to modify the sources of U-Boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can change if from kernel config:-

```
+CONFIG_CMDLINE="foo=1"
+CONFIG_CMDLINE_EXTEND=y

Check runtime:-
$cat /proc/cmdline
```